# How to Rewrite make .htaccess for site "replacement" (old site to subfolder, new site in root) while keeping the Google Love

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site on a domain existing for many years (10+) and are now changing the site from one CMS to another. This is a lengthy process to move the content and some of it will not move and should co-exist for some years forward.

I alleready moved the old site from the root (www.example.com) to a subfolder (www.example.com/_old). The old site had the follwing .htaccess to force www. on my domain since early 2007. I have deleted this on the .htaccess in the (www.example.com/_old/) folder.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now I stated the news site in another sub-dir (www.example.com/dp/) to keep the root empty with just a .htaccess and rewrite but what I really want is:

1. I want to access the new site on the root of the domain w/o www (example.com)
2. I want the old site to still serve as the main landing page for all old links from the "world" - primarily Google (www.example.com/_old/[whatever] from www.example.com/[whatever]
3. I want to make sure that when I move a page to the new site (www.example.com/_old/oldpage.html to example.com/newpage.html) I can redirect that URL specifically to the new site to avoid duplicate content.

I am here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_old/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /dp/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=307]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/_old/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is still with the new site in the sub-folder /dp/

Answer (score 0):

```
#if file or directory doesn't exist, check the _old directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_old
RewriteRule .* /_old/$0 [L]
#note that I omitted the redirect flag. That way the old url just work like they used to. If you really want you can just add them, but please, just give it a try. This might even fix problem nr. 3

# remove www. from everything except _old urls
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/_old
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=307]
```

Just to clarify a bit more. I the user request a old link like www.example.com/seafood.html the request if internally rewritten to /_old/seafood.html. If in the future you like to create a new page for this, you just create seafood.html in the root. This file will automatically take precedence over the same filename that is in the /_old folder.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really good idea in general. Though I have an old CMS (Joomla with links like: www.example.com/_old/component/option,com_fireboard/Itemid,186/func,view/catid,12/id,22992/#22992 and www.example.com/_old/content/view/57/122/ ) and the new CMS Drupal where I want to use nice, clean urls for the pages. So I would rather make a new redirect for the pages I move to 'translate' for Google.

Comment: I will try this out since it might be mew perfect than I see at first. Thanks again. I will get back after testing - though I will need to add a "translater" redirect when moving pages that change URL right?

Comment: Since you used oldpage.html I didn't suspect you were using a CMS. If you are using a CMS, `!-f` and `!-d` probably won't work.

Comment: `!` is `NOT`. `-f` and `-d` is file exists and directory exists, respectively. So `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means, there is no file with the path `REQUEST_FILENAME` in the file-system.